# Event handling change in Vue 3.0?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need to handle an event in a child component; check for a certain condition; if true, emit the "submit" event back to the parent so it's event handler will run.

The example below fires the parent's event handler once using Vue.js 2.6.11 (replacing "vue" with "@vue/composition-api"). With 3.0.0-rc.5, it fires ***twice***. Wondering if this is an intentional change, a bug, or me.

App.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
#app
  .container
    h1 Form Experiment
    FormGroup(@submit='onSubmit')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
import FormGroup from "@/components/FormGroup.vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    FormGroup,
  },
  setup() {
    const onSubmit = (): void => {
      alert("Parent event handler")
    }
    return { onSubmit }
  }
})
</script>
```

FormGroup.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
form(@submit.prevent='onFormSubmit', novalidate, autocomplete='on')
  slot Content needed in FormGroup
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormGroup",
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const check = ref(true) // evaluated elsewhere - simplified for this example
    const onFormSubmit = (): void => {
      if (check.value) {
        alert("Form is valid - sending event to parent")
        emit("submit")
      } else {
        alert("Form is not valid.") // so don't emit the event to parent
      }
    }

    return { check, onFormSubmit }
  }
})
</script>
```

Any thoughts regarding why **onSubmit()** in the parent fires twice in Vue.js 3.0.0-rc.5?

Comment: Maybe a bug caused by `<form>` being the root element? I'd be curious if the same thing happened if FormGroup was rooted as a `<div><form...` instead

Comment: @nstuyvesant I just tried your code in Vue 2 with `@vue/composition-api`, and it also fires twice, so I don't think this is a bug in Vue 3. Daniel's answer should provide a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is intended in Vue 3

> #### inheritAttrs
>
> Type: boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> Details:
>
> By default, parent scope attribute bindings that are not recognized as
> props will "fallthrough". This means that when we have a single-root
> component, these bindings will be applied to the root element of the
> child component as normal HTML attributes. When authoring a component
> that wraps a target element or another component, this may not always
> be the desired behavior. By setting inheritAttrs to false, this
> default behavior can be disabled. The attributes are available via the
> $attrs instance property and can be explicitly bound to a non-root
> element using v-bind.
>
> Note: this option does not affect class and style bindings.

docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#inheritattrs

Should be working (added `inheritAttrs: false`):

```html
<template lang="pug">
form(@submit.prevent='onFormSubmit', novalidate, autocomplete='on')
  slot Content needed in FormGroup
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormGroup",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const check = ref(true) // evaluated elsewhere - simplified for this example
    const onFormSubmit = (): void => {
      if (check.value) {
        alert("Form is valid - sending event to parent")
        emit("submit")
      } else {
        alert("Form is not valid.") // so don't emit the event to parent
      }
    }

    return { check, onFormSubmit }
  }
})
</script>
```

```js
const {
  defineComponent,
  createApp,
  ref,
} = Vue

const FormGroupFactory = (name, inheritAttrs) => defineComponent({
  name,
  inheritAttrs,
  setup(_, {
    emit
  }) {
    const onFormSubmit = () => {
      emit("evt", "@EVT")
      emit("submit", "@SUBMIT")
    }
    return {
      onFormSubmit
    }
  },
  template: document.getElementById("FormGroup").innerHTML
})


createApp({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      FormGroupOne: FormGroupFactory('FormGroupOne', true),
      FormGroupTwo: FormGroupFactory('FormGroupTwo', false),
    },
    setup() {
      const log = ref('');
      const onSubmit = (e) => {
        log.value = log.value + "Parent event handler" + e + "\n"
      }
      return {
        log,
        onSubmit
      }

    }
  })
  .mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <form-group-one @submit="onSubmit"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button> inheritAttrs: true</form-group-one>
    <form-group-two @submit="onSubmit"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button> inheritAttrs: false</form-group-two>
  </div>
  <pre>{{log}}</pre>
</div>

<template id="FormGroup">
  <form @submit.prevent="onFormSubmit" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="on">
    <slot>Content needed in FormGroup</slot>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: But `inheritAttrs` already [exists in Vue 2](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) (as of 2.4.0), and its docs are identical in Vue 3. I think `inheritAttrs` is just a workaround.

Comment: I didn't check on vue 2, so I can't speak to the behaviour in vue 2, but as you can see in the example, setting it to false does reduce to one call

Comment: so is it that `inheritAttrs: true` (which is the default) isn't working on vue2.6? AFAIK seems like vue 3 is behaving correctly

Comment: As it turns out, the behavior is actually the same in Vue 2 (plain) and Vue 2 w/`@vue/composition-api`, so I don't think it's a bug anymore, and the solution is indeed as you stated (to use `inheritAttrs: false`).

Comment: This works well. Odd that I did not encounter the same issue with Vue 2.6.11 and Composition API but your guidance was spot on. Thank you!